# What is the capability that permits access to WP-Admin?

Tags: wp-admin, user-roles

This is a very simple question but I have made great effort to find it already addressed on the stack. Basically I'm creating a new user role for a freelance web developer and trying to figure out what allows them to log into wp-admin. Does anyone know which exact setting provides that access? I've been trying to compare it with Editor.

Comment: What do you want these users to be able to do?

Answer (score 2):

Anyone with a login can access the admin area, even if they're just a subscriber that can read posts and nothing more.

The crucial difference is not in the login, but in what parts of the admin one gets access to. A subscriber will only be able to see his personal profile, for instance. And admin gets access to everything. Others get something inbetween.

If you build a new user role, you can determine exactly what he or she gets acces to, by assigning one or more of the [58 capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) to that role.

The general syntax to add a new role is like this: `add_role( $role, $display_name, $capabilities )`, where the last variable is an array of the capabilities you want to assign to this role. Only these capabilities will be available to those users in the admin area.

Answer (score 2):

You must add the `read` capability.

Answer (score 1):

In Woocommerce you will also need one of these

- manage_woocommerce
- view_admin_dashboard
- edit_others_shop_orders